# Does upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 retain previous downloaded app software?

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

Do I need to reload all app software such as kmoney, xsane etc after update?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade will not delete your installed software and and files. but it is better to backup your personal data before upgrading. Upgrade will install any newer versions of your installed software.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you do the upgrade.

If you upgrade through package management, you should retain most, if not all, of your installed applications.

If you upgrade using an ISO based media such as a DVD or USB, you may not retain the installed applications, however, you may be able to retain the files and settings in your home directory if you choose "something else"during installation and then set up your partitions and do *not*  format the partitions during installation.

Also, don't forget to back up your files before you begin.

Again, using standard methods such as the software center, `apt-get` or `sudo do release upgrade`  you should retain most or all of your installed applications.